# Calling a function from managed bean and after completion setting focus to a desired component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` which calls a method from managed bean. I want to add one more functionality to it. So after calling that particular function , I want to set focus to a `p:selectOneMenu`

My code is :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="particulars" filter="true"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                 value="#{receiptMB.selectedFeeSchemeDetail.planId}"
                 style="width:120px !important;">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{receiptMB.incomeSchemes}" var="acc"
                   itemLabel="#{acc.feeInstallment}" itemValue="#{acc.planId}" />
    <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{receiptMB.onIncomeSourceSelect()}"
            update=":messageGrowl :receiptEntryForm:planId
            :receiptEntryForm:newVouchDetails txtQty totalAmount
            particulars :receiptEntryForm:planId :receiptEntryForm:receiptSource
            advAmtRemaining advCheckBox amtPaid" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton value="#{bundle.add}" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                 partialSubmit="true" process="jvPanel autoCompleteData"
                 id="addVoucher" actionListener="#{receiptMB.loadTableData}"
                 update=":messageGrowl cmdSave :receiptEntryForm:newVouchDetails
                 txtQty totalAmount
                 particulars :receiptEntryForm:planId :receiptEntryForm:receiptSource
                 advAmtRemaining advCheckBox amtPaid">
</p:commandButton>
```

Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: First of all you should format your code properly. Makes it easier to read . Thanks.

Comment: There's also a lot of noise in the code which is irrelevant to the concrete question and therefore distracting to potential answerers.

Comment: Ok I wil try to simplify it.

Comment: You are updating a lot of components by manually specifying their ids with  the `update` attribute. Gathering and encompassing them into a container component like a `<h:panelGroup>` and specifying its `id` with the `update` attribute will better simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestContext in you action method as :

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.scrollTo("receiptEntryForm:particulars");
```

you can checkout primefaces documentation and showcase for more info.

Comment: I am not sure about why it did not work but its probably related that i may have mistyped the selectonemenu location, make sure correct path passed as argument to    context.scrollTo("<pathToComponent>");

Comment: when you set correct path argument it did work then?

Comment: can you paste what did you try in context.scrollTo method and is selectoneMenu component is inside another container such as tabView or accordionPanel?

Comment: I pasted as u suggested. selectOneMenu is inside panel.

Comment: scrollTo expects a clientId, so remove the leading colon.

Comment: vsevolod is right i edited the code without leading colon. if you inspect the selectonemenu with firebug or built-in browser developer tools you willl see client id and replace the parameter as needed.